# How to use String.format to convert a long to a String in currency format in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, string.format

I need to learn how to convert a `long` value into a currency formatted string in a `toString()` method with the following scenarios:

- If given long value = 9287, needs to be displayed as $92.87
- If given long value = -9287, needs to be displayed as $-92.87
- If given long value = 100000000, needs to be displayed as $1,000,000.00
- If given long value = 49, needs to be displayed as $0.49

Any help from string gurus is appreciated.

Comment: You should always post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please mention programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String [] args){

       DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00");

       //test with
       long num1 = 9287;
       long num2 = -9287;
       long num3 = 100000000;
       long num4 = 49;

       System.out.println("num1 = "+f.format(num1/100.0));
       System.out.println("num2 = "+f.format(num2/100.0));
       System.out.println("num3 = "+f.format(num3/100.0));
       System.out.println("num4 = "+f.format(num4/100.0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using Java. Try this :

```
            import java.text.NumberFormat;

            NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            System.out.println(f.format(doubleValue(yourVar)/100));
```

Comment: Yes, using java. Sorry should have mentioned that. So I'm unclear as to what the "doubleValue" part refers to. This seems to be along the path I was thinking of though . I want to return "String s".

Answer (score 0):

String.format() does not support currency format. So you need to insert currency symbol yourself or use `java.text` package.

```
package tests;

import java.util.Locale;

public class App201210130101 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long value;

    value = 9287;
    print(value);

    value = -9287;
    print(value);

    value = 100000000;
    print(value);

    value = 49;
    print(value);
}

public static void print(long value) {

    System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "$%,.2f", (double)value/100));
}

}
```

Comment: I ended up using a NumberFormat and it worked out great. This looks like a good option too. Thanks everyone for the input.